# WebappClassLoader and Hibernate memory leaks when undeploying?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

**EDIT**: Hibernate forum topic on this problem: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1035073

I'm using `hibernate-4.3.1`, `ehcache-core-2.6.7`, `c3p0-0.9.5-pre5` alongside with `Tomcat 7.0.27` and I'm experiencing large PermGen leak when undeploying application.

I've figured out, that there are lots of classes pinned by `WebappClassLoader` ([here is](http://pastebin.com/5ZbWm7HA) the list, as JProfiler shows. First number is count of objects of that class in memory)

Here is the code in `ContextListener.contextDestroyed()`:

```
@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    Debug.log.info("SERVER UNDEPLOY:");
    serviceManager.destroyServices();
    serviceManager = null; // this is static field :(

    for (Object o : C3P0Registry.getPooledDataSources()) {
        PooledDataSource dataSource = (PooledDataSource) o;
        try {
            Debug.log.info(String.format(
                    "-> deregistering C3P0 pool: size %s",
                    dataSource.getThreadPoolSize()));
            dataSource.close();
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Debug.log.error(String.format(
                    "   FAILED deregistering C3P0 pool: %s",
                    dataSource.getDataSourceName()), e);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }

    Debug.log.info("-> shutting down cache manager");
    CacheManager.getInstance().shutdown();

    Enumeration<Driver> drivers = DriverManager.getDrivers();
    while (drivers.hasMoreElements()) {
        Driver driver = drivers.nextElement();
        try {
            Debug.log.info(String.format(
                    "-> deregistering jdbc driver: %s", driver));
            DriverManager.deregisterDriver(driver);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            Debug.log.error(String.format(
                    "   FAILED deregistering driver %s", driver), e);
        }
    }

    Debug.log.info("-> shutting down Hibernate factories");
    Hibernate.factory.close(); //SessionFactory
    Hibernate.factory = null; // static field :(

    Debug.log.info("-> stopping logger");
    Debug.log.info("............  SERVER stop ...................");
    ((LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory()).stop();

}
```

I've tried to analyze GC roots of objects in profiler, but no success. Can anyone suggest why that could be?

Comment: Have you gone thorugh `MemoryLeakProtection` by Tomcat?,Read More @ http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/MemoryLeakProtection

Comment: yes. The code in question does JDBC driver deregistration and I'm already aware of static variables and how they can hold things. My app doesn't create threads itself and doesn't operate with ClassLoaders.

Answer (score 0):

i'm glad you are close()ing your DataSources in `contextDestroyed(...)`!

But you might also want to give a try to two new settings in c3p0 intended specifically to address memory leak issues in Tomcat and other ClassLoader-based hot-redeploy environments. Please see the [green box here](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#tomcat-specific) and the links from there.

(and please upgrade to the latest, 0.9.5-pre8. these are new features and i don't remember which 0.9.5 prerelease brought them in.)

Comment: I have removed c3p0 dependency at all and leaks are still there. The "green box" was studied again and gave no help. I've created Hibernate topic on these kind of leaks: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1035073